# Is there a geographic component to support for Trump's wall?

Tags: united-states, trump-wall

The largest factor in support for Donald Trump's proposed border wall is political affiliation: support is much higher among Republicans than among Democrats.  But is there a geographic component to that support?  For example, is a Republican in Laredo, Texas, more (or less) likely to support the wall than a Republican in Peoria, Illinois?

Answer (score 4):

Job approval for Trump is by far the biggest factor, even moreso than party affiliation. The New York Times recently did [an article about this](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/12/upshot/trump-border-wall-polls.html), based on polls from many sources. While looking just at the map may seem like there is a geographic component (fewer living near the border support the wall in most cases)...

[image: wall-by-state]

... the next chart shows that even over time, support follows Trump's approval ratings quite well.

[image: wall-vs-trump]

So it seems that geography is probably at best a side effect of the issue (or vice versa, depending on how you view US politics and the urban/rural divide). As they put it in the article:

> There is tentative evidence in the Fox data that the wall is
>   particularly unpopular in the relatively white and rural West, but
>   somewhat more popular, at least with respect to the president’s
>   approval rating, in the Northeast and inland South. This would follow
>   a familiar pattern in American politics: It mirrors the president’s
>   support in the presidential primary and tracks with longstanding
>   measures of racial resentment.

Comment: It would be more interesting to look at the map, if it was adjusted by the percentage of Republican voters in each state. As is, this is simply a map of where Republicans are popular.

Comment: I agree, but I couldn't find better numbers than this, and don't have the time to draw my own map. However, with the close way the poll numbers track each other over time, I suspect you could get close to a good map (with a couple outlier states) by finding a state-based Trump approval rating poll.